# How to let users create their accounts AFTER installing windows?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

So I would like to install windows 10 pro to a machine and have 3 accounts (1 administrator and two normal accounts) for my brother and his two children.

I want to setup some software on the machine as well (such as steam, office and other essentials)

But I want to ship it to them and then when they first boot it to have like the MS dialogue to create each account (enter email, set password etc)

Is that possible? It must be that's how OEM's ship prebuilds :P

How?

Also on top of everything above what would be the easiest way without installing any unnecessary bloatware to have a video file start playing after they setup the accounts and log in for the first time (I would like to make a video explaining to them the ropes of the system)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe its c:\windows\system32\sysprep\sysprep /oobe /generalize

You can create a unattended.xml file is the same folder to customize the experience.

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-unattended-media-do-automated-installation-windows-10

How to install Windows System Image Manager

Anyone can write an answer file manually. Microsoft offers the Windows System Image Manager (SIM) console available through the Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (ADK) to make it easier to create the file to install Windows 10 unattended.

To install the Windows System Image Manager, use these steps:

```
Download the Windows ADK installer for Windows 10 version 2004.
Double-click the adksetup.exe file to begin the installation.

Select the Install the Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit - Windows 10 to this computer option.
```

o prepare the environment to create a new answer file project, use these steps:

I have included this summary from the linked website.

```
Open Start.
Search for Windows System Image Manager and click the top result to open the console.
Click the File menu.

Select the Select Windows Image option.

Select Windows Image
Source: Windows Central
Navigate to the folder with the Windows 10 installation files exported.
Access the source folder.

Select the install.wim image file.

Install.wim file
Source: Windows Central

Click the Open button.

Important: Make sure that image is an install.wim file. Otherwise, if you have an install.esd image, this will not work.

Select the edition of Windows 10 you want to use. (Usually, you want to select the version that you're planning to install.)

Select edition of Windows 10
Source: Windows Central
Click the OK button.

Click the Yes button to create a new catalog file (if applicable).

Quick note: This process will take some time, but it's a one-time process. The .clg file will be saved in the same location where the install.wim is stored, and you can reuse it later on other projects.

Under the "Distribution Share" section, right-click on "Select a Distribution Share" and select the Create Distribution Share option.

Create distribution share
Source: Windows Central
Click the Create New Folder option in the dialog box.
Specify a name for the folder – for example, "Distribution" and select the folder.

Click the Open button.

Select distribution folder
Source: Windows Central
Click the File menu.

Select the Select Distribution Share option.

Select distribution share
Source: Windows Central
Locate the folder you recently created for the distribution files.
Click the Open button.
Click the File menu.

Select the New Answer File option.

Create Windows 10 answer file
Source: Windows Central
```

Comment: Thanks I will check on that but as far as I can understand right to this point without trying it out this will just install windows wont it? I want to install windows + drivers + 3rd party programs on the system . Also as far as I can understand if I enable oobe sysprep it will ask for a windows key as well can I avoid this step? (I will enter a valid key when I install windows my self)

Comment: You install windows,drivers,programs, and etc.  Then you run sysprep /oobe /generalize a second time.